# Makefile: using command output in conditional

Tags: bash, makefile, conditional-statements

In a makefile, I want to use a shell command such as command1=[some program] [--flags],  then use a condition to see whether or not the output contains a certain keyword using grep.

My code does not work:

```
var=$([command 1] | grep [keyword])
if [ -z ${var} ]; then \
[command 2, with variables in it]; \
[command 3, with variables in it]; \
fi
```

any idea why?

Comment: Put the commands you want to run in a shell script, and use [the `$(shell)` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) to run it and save its output in a variable.

Comment: Thank you. I need some of the local variables from the script in the command. Is it still possible to do?

Comment: Pass as arguments to the command or script.

Answer (score 1):

What you show is not make syntax, it is shell syntax. So I will assume that it is part of a make recipe. Your problem is then that:

1. Each line of a make recipes is passed to a different shell. So, you cannot pass shell variables from one line to the next. Use one single shell command list and line continuation (`; \`) to pass your entire recipe to one single shell.
2. Make expands the recipes before passing them to the shell. Escape the make expansions by doubling the `$` signs that you want to preserve (`$${var}`). Do the same for all shell variable expansions. You can also replace the `$()` command substitutions by the equivalent backtick notation `` instead of `$$()`.

   ```
    target: prerequisite ...
        var=`[command 1] | grep [keyword]`; \
        if [ -z "$${var}" ]; then \
            [command 2, with variables in it]; \
            [command 3, with variables in it]; \
        fi
   ```

Comment: I can't upvote yet because I'm new, but this worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Even if you can't upvote you can probably accept the answer, which will be useful to others trying to solve similar issues.